# AWS/GCP: Is it possible to have a VM with dynamic CPU/RAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to write my program so I can "add more threads" to scale. This would mean using a standard library API to create more threads, and using only a single VM instance that dynamically scales from 1 core to 128 cores as needed.

Is there any cloud provider/OS combo that would allow me to automatically add more CPU cores and RAM to my guest OS on demand as utilisation approaches 100%?

I understand this would need to be implemented in the AWS/GCP hypervisor and the guest OS.

If not, is this possible in the future?

I know FAAS exists but I do not want to rely on network based storage - I just want to use disk storage on a single instance.

Comment: What you are asking seems to be anti-pattern for several reasons. Can you please be more specific? You won't get hypervisor access unless you rent the entire bare-metal. To change the `flavor`/`t-shirt`/`instance-type` you need to stop the VM, unless you install your own hypervisor and enable `HotAdd`. Lambda/Cloud Functions and the built-in monitoring systems are there to be used. If you want to build everything from scratch install Xen and have fun ;)

Comment: @NeoAnderson I am not asking for access to the hypervisor, I am saying that the cloud operators (GCP/AWS) hypervisor would need to know that my guest VM OS CPU is at 100% and to add more CPU cores to the VM as its running. FAAS moves the code artefacts to the compute. I am asking if the reverse can be true - moving the compute to the running code as its needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The built in monitoring systems provide memory/CPU metrics out of the box. For zero-downtime in GCP I recommend having a look into MIGs(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups). Regular instances require to be stopped to add/remove memory or CPUs(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance). As for the last part of your question, I'm afraid I don't have the expertise to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a single VM that is scaled (by adding cores) by the cloud operator with no downtime.

Comment: I am not aware of any cloud vendor (AWS, GCP, Azure, Alibaba, IBM, etc.) that offers what you are looking for (dynamically adding cores). This is called vertical scaling. Vertical scaling is a manual process. Look into horizontal scaling to increase computer resources.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, such VMs aren't available for GCP and AWS.

---

**GCP**

Have a look at the documentation [Machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types):

> A machine type is a set of virtualized hardware resources available to
> a virtual machine (VM) instance, including the system memory size,
> virtual CPU (vCPU) count, and persistent disk limits. In Compute
> Engine, machine types are grouped and curated by families for
> different workloads. You can choose from general-purpose,
> memory-optimized, and compute-optimized families.
>
> **You must choose a machine type when you create an instance. You can select from a number of predefined machine types in each machine type
> family.** If the predefined machine types do not meet your needs, you
> can create your own custom machine types.

and at the [Changing the Machine Type of a Stopped Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance):

> **You can change the machine type of a stopped instance** if it is not part of a managed instance group.

So, as you can see, it's not possible to have dynamic CPU/RAM for GCP VMs.

As a possible workaround for GCP, you can try to file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

---

**AWS**

Have a look at the documentation [Instance types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html):

> When you launch an instance, the instance type that you specify
> determines the hardware of the host computer used for your instance.
> Each instance type offers different compute, memory, and storage
> capabilities and are grouped in instance families based on these
> capabilities. Select an instance type based on the requirements of the
> application or software that you plan to run on your instance.

then at the [Changing the instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html):

> As your needs change, you might find that your instance is
> over-utilized (the instance type is too small) or under-utilized (the
> instance type is too large). If this is the case, you can change the
> size of your instance.

and at the section [Resizing an Amazon EBS–backed instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html):

> **You must stop your Amazon EBS–backed instance before you can change
> its instance type**.

also at the section [Migrating an instance store-backed instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html):

> When you want to move your application from one instance store-backed
> instance to an instance store-backed instance with a different
> instance type, you must migrate it by creating an image from your
> instance, and then launching a new instance from this image with the
> instance type that you need.

As you can see, it's quite the same story for AWS VMs.

You can try to request such feature by following [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/send-feedback-aws/).